# UnitTestIsolation instrumentation failed to initialize. Please restart Visual Studio and rerun this test

Tags: unit-testing, microsoft-fakes

My unit test fails on line shimscontext.create.

Error is: UnitTestIsolation instrumentation failed to initialize. Please restart Visual Studio and rerun this test

As per existing posts, I tried to install NUnit adapter and I tried running it from test explorer, still no luck.

Any comments on what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15607555/visual-studio-2012-fakes-unittestisolation-instrumentation-failed-to-initialize

Answer (score 3):

Go to your TestProject **Properties** -> Under Debug section Check the

> "ENABLE NATIVE CODE DEBUGGING"

checkbox.

This is should do.

Comment: I couldn't figure out why this fixed it for me, but it did. Only one test that messes about with AppDomains needs it. Other tests don't fail though the code can be identical.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar issue. Make sure you are using the msbuild.exe located in the 12.0 folder and run the tests with vstest.exe instead of mstest.exe.

VStest Command line:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155796.aspx

Comment: Still curious why MSTest doesn't work as expected. Using team city this isn't the most preferable way but this is the only post which helped me out having unit tests working on the team city build server.

Answer (score 0):

This error is reported when the shims runtime is unable to connect to the IntelliTrace profiler, which provides runtime instrumentation necessary to detour CLR methods. The IntelliTrace profiler is automatically started by the CLR when the COR_PROFILER environment variable is set for the test runner process (vstest.executionengine*.exe). If the shims runtime reports this error, it means something went wrong and the COR_PROFILER variable was not set correctly and the IntelliTrace profiler was not loaded.

There are several potential causes of this problem. It is hard to tell without a closer look. In Visual Studio 2012, you can find additional information about it from the application event log. In Visual Studio 2013, this information is included in the exception error message itself.

Comment: Hello, I did not find any information in application event log.

Comment: We would need to take a look at diagnostics logs from your environment to troubleshoot this problem. I recommend submitting it as a new bug at http://connect.microsoft.com/visualstudio.