# UnitTestIsolationException: Debug Unit Test at ShimsContext.Create

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.0, microsoft-fakes, shim

When I am trying to debug a Unit test, I receive the following exception message:

> UnitTestIsolation instrumentation failed to initialize. Please restart
>   Visual Studio and rerun this test

With this stack trace:

> at
>   Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.UnitTestIsolation.UnitTestIsolationRuntime.InitializeUnitTestIsolationInstrumentationProvider()
>   at
>   Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.Shims.ShimRuntime.CreateContext()
>   at Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.ShimsContext.Create()    at
>   Sample.Business.Tester.ProcessorManagerTest.Test_first_run_ever() in
>   d:\Folder1\Sample.Business.Tester\ProcessorManagerTest.cs:line 62

The code is:

```
var prc = new ProcessorManager(ProcessRepository,ProcessStatusRepository);
using (ShimsContext.Create())
{
    ShimDateTime.NowGet = () => new DateTime(2015, 10, 1);
    prc.Run();
}
```

The exception is thrown at `ShimsContext.Create()`.

I have reviewed the [Visual Studio 2012 fakes UnitTestIsolation instrumentation failed to initialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15607555), and tried all the steps there but doesn't work for me. I am not using Nunit.

Comment: What is "ProcessorManager"?

Comment: @doobop hi, this is a custom class created by me, the error appears afterwards

Comment: When I try to reproduce this, it works as expected (I'm using VS 2013 and .NET 4.6).  I'm not able to go back to 2012 and .NET 4.0 easily, so I haven't tried that explicitly.  Does it still fail if you comment out the ProcessorManager?  What about if you stub out the constructor and/or Run?  Can you include the constructor?  Sometimes it's something in the custom class that causes later calls to fail.

Comment: @doobop thanks for the comment, it works OK on VS2013 here as well, the issue is in VS2012, I am not able to migrate it because we have a 2012 Server Builder and that is not going to change yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is a problem with your Unit testing project, related to fakes or shims, do the following:

1. In references, remove these dlls:

   - Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes
   - Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework
   - System.4.0.0.0.Fakes
   - mscorlib.4.0.0.0.Fakes
2. Also in "Fakes" folder, remove these files:

   - mscorlib.fakes
   - System.fakes
3. Add the dlls:

   - Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes
   - Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework

from the following source path: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies`

4. Right click on the "System.dll" and choose in the contextual menu "Add fake assembly".
5. Clean project.
6. Build project.

Comment: Incredible, I have followed the same steps before and didn't remeber, but this definately solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Similar error here. Could be resolved by repairing the VS installation with the "Visual Studio Installer". VS Enterprise 2017 Version 15.6.6